# How to create and process string on FreeBSD Bourne shell?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I'm working on a script under FreeBSD to back-up all running bhyve VMs. The goal is to identify all running VMs, stop one-by-one, wait for its PID to finish, back-up, and restart.

I know that I can command from the shell `vm list` and obtain:

```
root@mellonas:/ # vm list
NAME            DATASTORE       LOADER      CPU    MEMORY    VNC                  AUTOSTART    STATE
dockers         default         grub        2      4096M     -                    No           Stopped
freebsd         default         bhyveload   1      256M      -                    No           Stopped
guacamole       default         grub        1      512M      -                    No           Stopped
mediaserver     default         grub        4      3048M     -                    Yes [2]      Running (2046)
mx-server       default         grub        1      1024M     -                    Yes [3]      Running (2609)
nextcloud       default         bhyveload   1      1024M     -                    Yes [4]      Running (2783)
pf              default         bhyveload   2      1512M     -                    Yes [1]      Running (1766)
zm              default         grub        4      2548M     -                    Yes [5]      Running (2957)
```

As I have no experience with script coding, I've written this script below that requires updating the VM list manually to add/remove new ones:

```
#!/bin/sh
#

#
# Variables

now=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S")                # Run date
maindir=/raid/vm/                               # bhyve VM's directory
vmbkpdir=/raid/cifs/vmbackups/$now              # Back-up directory
log_file=$maindir"/vmcopy.log"                  # Log file
vm_list="pf mediaserver mx-server nextcloud zm" # List of VMs to back-up

#
# Process log entries

log()
{
timestamp=$(date +"[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]")
parm="$1"
  if [ -e $log_file ];
     then
     echo "$timestamp copy bhyve VMs: $parm" >> $log_file
  else
    echo "$timestamp copy bhyve VMs: Log file created" > $log_file
    echo "$timestamp copy bhyve VMs: $parm" >> $log_file
  fi
}

#
# Process VM back-up

save()
{
vm=$1
vmdir=$maindir$vm
log "vm directory $vmdir"
log "Stopping $vm"
vm stop $vm
sleep 60
cd $vmbkpdir
log "Creating tar ball"
tar -zcvf $vm.tar.gz $vmdir                     # Change to zfs snapshot if desired
log "Restarting vm"
vm start $vm
log "*** Copy completed ***"
}


#
# Main

log "*** Script started ***"
log "vm backup directory $vmbkpdir"
log "Creating back-up directory"
mkdir $vmbkpdir

for vms in $vm_list; do                         # Loop through VMs
        log "${vms}"
        save "${vms}"
done

log "*** End of script ***"
```

I'd like to:

1. Capture the VM list from the output of **vm list**
2. Capture the running VMs to process (stop, wait for PID, back-up, restart)

Comment: That is not the Bourne shell, note.  It is the Almquist shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 2nd question is ambiguous. Question 1 is straightforward. This obtains the relevant process IDs:

```
PIDS=`vm list | grep ' Running ' | sed -e 's;.* Running ;;' | tr -d '()'`
echo $PIDS
for PID in $PIDS; do ps wwup $PID; done
```

Comment: Re: question 2 

After capturing the vm list output I'll need to get into a loop to:

1 - stop the VM

That can be done with: vm stop <vm name> (Need to capture vm name from the output of vm list)

2 - Wait for PID

The time to stop the VM will depend on what's is running. Need to capture PID, remove the parentheses from vm list output, and have the scrip waiting for that PID to finish.

3 - Back-up 

command from the script: vm snapshot <vm name>

4 - Restart

command from the script: vm start <vm name>

Comment: Using `awk {print $1}` to pick out <vm name> isn't hard, and pid can go in $PID (the `tr` above stripped parens). More tricky is waiting for the `vm stop` to complete: `while \`ps p $PID | wc -l\` -gt 1; do sleep 1; done`